# SQL - Buscar o nome dos pacientes que tiveram mais consultas no mês de janeiro de 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server

Olá, gostaria de saber como faço para fazer essa consulta: "Buscar o nome dos pacientes que tiveram mais consultas no mês de janeiro de 2016".

```
 select * from PACIENTES  
 select * from CONSULTAS
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estas são as fotos da minha tabela

Comment: coloque aqui a estrutura das suas duas tabelas.. medicos e consulta,

Comment: @GuilhermeLucas: como se define "tiveram mais consultas? Isto é, é para listar até quantos pacientes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A listagem das tabelas não identifica qual é cada tabela, mas presumo que a primeira tabela seja a de consultas (pois contém a data e o valor da consulta) e a segunda tabela seja a de informações dos pacientes.

Eis uma possível solução, que emprega variáveis para armazenar o periodo da consulta e também a quantidades de pacientes com mais consultas a listar.

```
-- código #1
-- quantidade de pacientes a listar
declare @QtdPL int;
set @QtdPL= 10; 

-- período a emitir
declare @DataInicio date, @DataFim date;
set @DataInicio= convert(date, '1/1/2016', 103);
set @DataFim= convert(date, '31/1/2016', 103);

--
with MaisConsultas as (
SELECT top (@QtdPL) RGPACIENTE, count(*) as QtdC
  from CONSULTAS
  where cast(DATA_HORA as date) between @DataInicio and @DataFim
  group by RGPACIENTE
  order by count(*) desc
)
SELECT A.RGPACIENTE, B.NMPACIENTE
  from MaisConsultas as A
       left join PACIENTES as B on B.RGPACIENTE = A.RGPACIENTE
  order by A.QtdC desc;
```

O código acima não foi testado; comunique qualquer dúvida.

Comment: Desculpe pela falta de clareza na pergunta, muito obrigado pela solução, deu certo! Muito obrigado mesmo!